# How to find German battle accounts

Tags: germany, military-records, research-methods, world-war-2

I’m wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. My uncle was shot down by a German night fighter, which was apparently confirmed by obtained German documents a year after. The documents detail May 4, 1944 at Montdidier air field by the Germans as to which planes were shot down and the aftermath. Does anyone know where I might locate these specific documents. I’ve been told the German fighters kept excellent records, so it would be great to read their accounting of that night.